# how defines the character encoding language of xml file acording the Area

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to make input field that anyone frome anywere.
Can type in the input field in his language 
then I want to export this value in xml file

1 - how can I defines the character encoding language of xml
    acording the area if some user write in chinse so i need that other user in china can read
    this value in chinse **Chinese (Taiwan) - - > zh-tw**.
    **English (United States) - -> en-us**.
    ,if some other user write value in German lanugage I need that
    other user from german can read that value (**German (Luxembourg) - - > de-lu**)
    acording to table Language Codes.
2 - i serch in the google and i found this code:

```
<l:l10n xmlns:l="http://google.com" 
    language="it"
    english-language-name="Italian">
```

did there is some defines like   **charset=utf-8** ? like in tag html META ?

Thx alot

Answer (score 0):

The character encoding of an XML file is defined in the XML declaration at its start, such as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. It has nothing to do with the language of the text, and the encoding cannot be changed within a document.

There is hardly any need to set the encoding as different for different languages. Use UTF-8; it covers all characters, and any program that can read XML data can handle UTF-8.

The recommended way to specify the language of an element is the `xml:lang` attribute.